# How can I place my email processes/routine outside of my frontend server (Rails 3.2/devise/sendgrid/heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sendgrid

In order to free up my frontend server, I'd like to place all the requests sent to sendgrid (
authentificaiton, confirmation, passwiord reset and transactionnal emaisl such as "no visit for a long time" email and the daily email we send.

It's necessary as we plan to need to keep all the memory and power of the main server for the web app itself and it includes displaying pages as quickly as possible. So we'd like to keep all the emails routines from eating some of our main web app server memory/power.

Now everything is on one single server (on a dyno on Heroku) (plus the database).

As we plan to have a lot of traffic on the front end, I think it would make sense to create a dyno reserved only for email process (let's call it the "email server/dyno".

But it should talk to the app and database

- for ex if a user signs up, the main dyno with the web app has to send a message to the "email server"
- another ex: I'll have to access the same database to use a cron to see if I need to send an email if a user subscribed 8 weeks ago and and has never signed in on the website.

So to keep it short,

How can I create set up another server that would only deal with emails

Should I put all the same gems and environment

How can the "email server" talk to the main web app and the database?

Any advice or resource on the web that explains how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do this is my own apps is with Resque and Resque Mailer.  Resque is a queue based on redis that you can run using a heroku worker.  Here are some resources that might help you get started with that:

- https://github.com/resque/resque
- http://www.slideshare.net/homanj/background-jobs-with-resque
- http://blog.leshill.org/blog/2011/04/03/using-resque-and-resque-scheduler-on-heroku.html

Resque Mailer is a plugin that lets you background your emails from ActionMailer using Resque.  You can find more details on their github README:

https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer